# Get Unique values from 2 cells

Tags: worksheet-function

I have a spreadsheet in Excel that contains 2 columns with country codes.  I want to compare the two columns and return any values that are in one column but not the other.

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| UK,DE,US | UK,DE,SA | US | SA |

I have a big excel to due to which i want to extract this using a formula.

Comment: Which spreadsheet software are you using? What have you tried so far? Are there always 3 entries in columns A and B or does the number vary?

Comment: I suggested some edits to make it clear however couldn't figure out what you meant by *"I have a big excel to due to which i want to extract this using a formula."*  Can you rephrase that?

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to convert the two text strings into arrays using [TEXTSPLIT](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textsplit-function-b1ca414e-4c21-4ca0-b1b7-bdecace8a6e7) then use [MAP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-function-48006093-f97c-47c1-bfcc-749263bb1f01) on each array to check each value against the other array to determine in  a [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function if there is a match.  Using the [LET](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/let-function-34842dd8-b92b-4d3f-b325-b8b8f9908999) function enables storing intermediary values in variables so that they can be reused in calculations

##### Steps

1. Check if there is a match by trying to [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) the opposing array on each value.  This would return the value if it existed, or an error if it did not
   `FILTER(<array>,<array>=<value>)`
2. Wrapping the [FILTER](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759) function in [IFERROR](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/iferror-function-c526fd07-caeb-47b8-8bb6-63f3e417f611) allows returning `0` (arbitrary choice) instead of an error.
   `IFERROR(FILTER(<array>,<array>=<value>),)`
3. An IF condition based on `0` returns the value if TRUE, or NULL if FALSE
   `IF(IFERROR(FILTER(<array>,<array>=<value>),)=0,<value>,"")`
4. [MAP](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/map-function-48006093-f97c-47c1-bfcc-749263bb1f01) was used to pass the array of values to test into a [LAMBDA](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) function that contained the formula.  The output would be an array of rows that are either empty or have a
   unique value.
5. [TEXTJOIN](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/textjoin-function-357b449a-ec91-49d0-80c3-0e8fc845691c) converts the array to a string while stripping out any empty values
6. [HSTACK](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/hstack-function-98c4ab76-10fe-4b4f-8d5f-af1c125fe8c2) created a 2-column array with unique values from cell1 in col1 and unique values from cell2 in col2

##### Excel Formula

```
=LET(
 ar1A, TEXTSPLIT(A2,,","),
 ar2A, TEXTSPLIT(B2,,","),
 ar1B, MAP(ar1A,LAMBDA(r,IF(IFERROR(FILTER(ar2A,ar2A=r),0)=0,r,""))),
 ar2B, MAP(ar2A,LAMBDA(r,IF(IFERROR(FILTER(ar1A,ar1A=r),0)=0,r,""))),
 HSTACK(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,ar1B),TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,ar2B))
 )
```

<sup><sub>**One Value found per cell**</sub></sup>
[image]

<sup><sub>**Multiple Values found in a cell**</sub></sup>
[image]

<sup><sub>**No Values found in one cell**</sub></sup>
[image]